# I am playing Pixelmon for minecraft and I want to install the fast building mod to use while I play. Is this possible, how would I do it?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-mods, minecraft-pixelmon

Pretty much the title. I want to play pixelmon with fast-build as well. If I can  how would I do this? I use forge so please try to keep it available for forge exclusively. Thanks!

Comment: Hi @AceTrainerAlyssa, please read [ask]

Answer (score 0):

You click on the windows key and the "r" key at same time it should open up a tap in that tap type in %appdata% that should open up a folder in the folder you should see the names of all the different games you have click on one that should say pixelmon in that folder look for a mods for if their is not one then make one and add the mod. It is as easy as that.